# Golang : for loop over map goes into infinite loop even after value is updated

Tags: for-loop, go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    mapVal := map[string]string{
        "a": "k",
    }
    a := []string{"a", "b"}

    for i := range a {
        for _, ok := mapVal[a[i]]; ok; {
            i++
            fmt.Printf("the value of i is %d", i)
        }
    }

}
```

I did loop over the map which is a nested loop `_, ok := mapVal[a[i]]; ok;`. For the first iteration i equals to 0 and a[0] == "a" which returns the value(_) and ok(bool) as true but for the second iteration value i is incremented and i equals to 1 and a[1] == "b" which means the ok(bool) should be false but it is returned as true and the loop goes for infinite.

Comment: The first part where you read the value from the map is evaluated once, and `ok` is set to true. The loop condition is `ok`, which is true, so it loops forever.

Comment: Why you're using nested "for"? Map keys are unique، so if you want to check the map contains the key (over iteration of string-list by first "for"), it's enough to use a simple "if" instead of second "for"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with your inner loop. It does not reassign the value of ok for next time and if it evaluates true once, it goes into infinite loop. Here is my updated:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    mapVal := map[string]string{
        "a": "k",
    }
    a := []string{"a", "b"}

    for i := range a {
        for _, ok := mapVal[a[i]]; ok; {
            i++
            fmt.Printf("the value of i is %d\n", i)
            _, ok = mapVal[a[i]]
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using a [traditional for loop](https://go.dev/ref/spec#ForClause) in the inner loop.

It has the format:

```golang
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
}
```

`i := 0` is the `InitStmt`, `i < 10` is the `Condition`, and `i++` is the `PostStmt`. The `PostStmt` is run every loop iteration.

In your case, the `mapVal` access is a part of the `InitStmt` and the `ok` is a part of the `Condition`, but there is no `PostStmt`.

So, because the `InitStmt` is only run once at the beginning of the for loop, the value of `ok` never changes.